# Self attach using ptrace?

Tags: linux, pthreads, ptrace

Is it possible to ptrace the same process from a thread in that process? I found a discussion at [1] which seems to suggest a way which (may or may not work) seems to be bit involved to me as I am not intimately familiar with pthreads API. Has anybody tried this? Any code pointer would be great.

[1] http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/ptrace_self_attach.html

Answer (score 0):

You most emphatically do *not* want to use POSIX threads (pthreads) for this.  POSIX threads introduce a whole new set of application semantics which simply do not apply here.

The second paragraph explains how to do this the right way:

*And for the first one I found a reasonable way to avoid the problem: the
debugging thread can do a "vfork()" (or, if vfork() does something bad in
libc, do the direct "clone(CLONE_VFORK|CLONE_MM)" thing) to have a new
thread that is in a _different_ thread group, but is able to ptrace and
also is "synchronized" with the VM, simply because it shares it with all
the other threads it might want to debug*

This mechanism is how user-space debuggers like gdb(1) and crash(8) work: they create either a closely-coupled child process using vfork(2) or use a similar Linux-specific clone(2) system call.

If fact, this is how every program except the primeval init(1) program is run: a current process forks, and one process [usually the child] then exec(2)' the desired program to overwrite its execution environment.

Comment: When you say "this mechanism" is commonly used, you really mean `clone()` without the `CLONE_VM` flag, right?  So that is radically different from the approach outlined in your quote.  Linus's quote also appears to be using `vfork()` and `CLONE_VFORK` wrongly, since according to the `vfork` man page, the new thread isn't able to ptrace -- the only thing it can legally do is call `exec` or `exit`.  Probably `clone()` with `CLONE_VM` and not `CLONE_VFORK` would work as Linus described.